# How to import a custom package into another? Getting error package "packagename" does not exist

Tags: java, import

So right now in my code I have this:

```
package pokemonbattle;
import pokemon.Pokemon.*;
public class PokemonBattle { //Do stuff }
```

and then I also have:

```
package pokemon;
public class Pokemon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {}

    public String getName(int pokemon) {
        //stuff
    }
```

Except that I'm getting the error "Package pokemon.Pokemon does not exist." When it does. The file name it's under is called Pokemon, but I've tried using different capitalization but nothing is working. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: According to what you wrote Pokemon is a class, not a package. Sorry, but I think I don't understand the question.

Comment: "When it does" yes? Where? You have a class with that name, but also a package?

Answer (score 1):

Packages are like directories and you should put your files into the place specified by their package. In each directory can either be files (classes, interfaces, ..) or other sub directories.

When you do

```
package pokemon;
public class Pokemon {
```

You express that this is the `Pokemon.java` file in the `\pokemon` directory. In other words `\pokemon\Pokemon.java`.

To use that class in another place you do either

```
import pokemon.Pokemon;
```

to import just that one class specifically or you do

```
import pokemon.*;
```

to import all the classes in that package (but not sub-packages thereof) When you say `pokemon.Pokemon.*` it's looking for a *directory* named `\pokemon\Pokemon\` which doesn't exist.

Comment: It's still saying that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ella did you change it to `import pokemon.*` or the other one? If so, and it still complains check that you actually place the files in folders like that.

Comment: They're all in the same folder, netbeans projects. I did change it to both both the answers you suggested, but it's not working. Would I need to export the Pokemon package file to zip? Currently it's just a folder. I don't think that'd be necessary though.

Comment: @Ella In netbeans they aren't directly visible as folders, they are shown as package https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=a-BkOK1YzjI#t=56 (I don't use netbeans so I hope this is still accurate :) If you look at the project with a regular file explorer you should see a directory that contains all the folders that correspond to your packages though. And nothing needs to be zipped to work in java.